# Using .htaccess to redirect only certain non existing url's

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following scenario

I have some url's that exist and some url's that do not exist with the following structure

http://site.co.za/component/docman/cat_view/388-documents-reports/test/sss/test/123
http://site.co.za/component/docman/cat_view/388-documents-reports/file/asdsa
http://site.co.za/component/docman/cat_view/388-documents-reports/sadas
http://site.co.za/component/docman/cat_view/388-documents-reports/sadsad

What I'm trying to achieve is when any url that contains **component/docman/cat_view** does not exist it needs to link to the parent url

for example

http://site.co.za/component/docman/cat_view/388-documents-reports/test/sss/test/123

needs to redirect to

http://site.co.za/component/docman/cat_view/388-documents-reports

http://site.co.za/component/docman/cat_view/388-documents-reports/file/asdsa

needs to redirect to http://site.co.za/component/docman/cat_view/388-documents-reports

so in other words all urls that contain component/docman/cat_view need to redirect to the url plus the first parameter after docman

CAn this be done using the .htaccess file together with mod rewrite and how if it can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes using 301 redirects

see below for tutorial

```
http://www.phatz.com/301redirect.php
```